# Laravel Auth, custom database & table, {"error":{"type":"ErrorException","message":"Undefined index: password"

Tags: php, laravel

Creating a login route & function using Laravel's Auth class and my database.  Not using Eloquent due to the large legacy database that must be used.

I know SHA1 shouldn't be used but the thousands of accounts in the database use it and I haven't migrated.

```
Route::post('login', function() {
    $user = array(
        'username_c' => Input::get('username'),
        'password_c' => sha1(Input::get('password'))
    );

    if(Input::has('username') && Input::has('password')) {
        if(Auth::attempt($user)) {

            return json_encode(array('result' => true));
        }
    }

    return json_encode(array('result' => false));
});
```

*ONLY* when I enter valid credentials, it spits back this error in the console:

```
{"error":{"type":"ErrorException","message":"Undefined index: password","file":"\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Auth\/DatabaseUserProvider.php","line":135}}
```

What could be the problem here?  I edited app/config/auth.php and changed the `'table'` to my table, and the `'driver'` to `'database'`

From reading Laravel's docs., that's all I need to change.  What's causing this?

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the line that is being referenced, you see this:

```
$plain = $credentials['password'];
```

The authentication is expecting a `'password'` field to exist in the credentials provided to `Auth::attempt`, and you're giving it `'password_c'` instead, which is why you're getting that error.

The second line in that method is this:

```
 return $this->hasher->check($plain, $user->getAuthPassword());
```

This is basically checking whether the plain password provided in the input matches the value that is stored in the database.  This means that your input key name *does not need to match* the name of the database column.  The name of the database column is determined by the `$user->getAuthPassword()` method call above.  You will need to make the key that you pass to `Auth::attempt` to be `'password'`, though, instead of `'password_c'`.

But this isn't just going to work, because as you've probably already noticed in the second line above  that class is going to expect an actual instance of a `User` model, and by your own admission you don't have any Eloquent models.

My suggestion would be to go ahead and create the user eloquent model, because I believe you're going to have to.  You don't have to turn all of your tables into models, but if you want authentication to work with Laravel's `Auth` facade then I don't think there's any way around it.

**Update**

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19880068/697370) also has a good method for updating your current passwords to use the Laravel hash during authentication attempts with a fallback to using MD5 (the old hash function, in your case you could use sha1).

**Update 2**

You need to change your authentication logic to look something like this:

```
Route::post('login', function() {
    if(Input::has('username') && Input::has('password')) {
        $user = array(
            'username' => Input::get('username'),
            'password' => sha1(Input::get('password'))
        );
        if(Auth::attempt($user)) {

            return json_encode(array('result' => true));
        }
    }

    return json_encode(array('result' => false));
});
```

Ensure that your user model's `getAuthPassword` method returns the name of the password column and the `getAuthIdentifier` returns the name of the username column.

Comment: I changed the column name in MySQL from `password_c` to `password` and it's not spitting back the error.  However... It's returning with false although the credentials should provide true.

Comment: Leave your table as is, but create the user model.  If the name of the column with the password isn't `'password'`, then you can specify the column name inside of `getAuthPassword` method in the user model.  This way if you have other applications that are using the same database they will remain unaffected.

Comment: For now, by changing the column name, is there anyway I could get it to work?  It's not spitting back an error but returning false.

Comment: yes, i believe you're going to have to create that user model no matter what.  the authentication process is calling `getAuthPassword` on a user instance, and, without a model class, there's no way for it to obtain that instance.

Comment: There's already a User model in app/models.  What do I modify to make it work as it should?

Comment: I'm asking what do I do as far as editing app/models/User.php so it will work?