# Laravel Auth Basic Hashing

Tags: authentication, laravel

**LARAVEL BASIC AUTH**

I have table `user` like

```
id | username | userpassword
```

I'm using `username` and `userpassword` to matching data from `user` table.

In field `userpassword` I'm not using Laravel hash like `Hash::make('secretpassword');`, I'm using `md5 hash`. How to set post password variable to `md5 hash` so that I can pass and login?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19878319/laravel-4-auth-use-md5-instead-of-the-integrated-hashmake

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17710897/how-to-use-sha1-encryption-instead-of-bcrypt-in-laravel-4

Comment: but i'm using basic auth there. how?

Answer (score 0):

1. You're going to have to change the name of the column "userpassword" to just "password". Hopefully, in future Laravel versions you will be allowed to change the name of this column for Laravel Auth to work
2. Laravel Auth requires you use their Hash::make(). Honestly, its a good idea to do so.