# How to change Bcrypt to Sha1 when user login with using oauth2 or via web in Laravel 5

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, laravel-5

When register new user, I have change the method in App/Service/Resgitrar.php:

```
public function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => sha1($data['password']), // default is bcrypt
    ]);
}
```

It works fine. When I register for new user, my password `12345678` is hashed to `7c222fb2927d828af22f592134e8932480637c0d`,

But, I have problem when I login, and sure it cannot used with oauth2..

Please help me, I'm a newbie in Laravel 5.

Comment: What kind of service uses that sha1 hash to check the hashed passwords? Also, don't use the sha1 function to hash passwords. Laravel uses Bcrypt for a reason..

Comment: i have database with 500 + users, it's generated using sha1 in codeigniter, now i want to migrate to laravel 5.. i have no service sha1, can you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Not recommended** - You could change the hash using the solution in [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17710897/how-to-use-sha1-encryption-instead-of-bcrypt-in-laravel-4). It was for laravel 4. But the same principles should apply. I am not sure though. It is however, recommended to use bcrypt as it is a hell lot more secure than SHA1

**Better solution** Migrate the current SHA1 hashes to bcrypt.
A migration strategy can have the following steps

1. Add a new column in your table, name it `password_new` / something else that you like.
2. When a user logs in, you have the real password. Check bcrypt hash of the submitted password from the `password_new` field. 
   If the value is not set, fallback to SHA1 check. If the password matches with SHA1 hash, hash the real password to bcrypt and save it in `password_new` column. 
   Then resume the current login flow. If not, display login error message.
3. Clear all user sessions.
4. When all users have migrated to the brcypt, drop the current `password`storing column and rename `password_new` to `password`
5. Remove checks for SHA1 from application logic.

**Note**: Steps 3,4,5 are optional but they are recommended to prevent long term bloating.