# custom auth and hashing laravel 5.1

Tags: php, authentication, md5, laravel-5.1

I have an existing database.

```
users :
username => varchar
password => md5 hashing
```

I am new to laravel, I was try to create simple login and register from laravel [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication#included-routing), thats work fine, 
but in docs are create for laravel,
now I want to create same login/register but with existing datas.

I was read some Question from [How to use SHA1 encryption instead of BCrypt in Laravel 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17710897/how-to-use-sha1-encryption-instead-of-bcrypt-in-laravel-4/17719586#17719586)
but I dont understand how to use it.

any adv?

sory for my bad grammer.

Comment: What you don't understand there exactly ? he wrote the whole steps you need to do and even wrote the code there for you all you need to do is copy-paste.

Comment: `routes`. I was done for copy-paste. but i dont know what to do next.. i realy new in laravel.

Comment: What routes? you should use laravel the same.just change `hash('sha1', $value);` to `md5` and then you'll have laravel authentication using md5.

Comment: routes like `Route::get('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');`. sory if my question make you confused.

Comment: Do you mean to have previous passwords in the form of md5 hash?

Comment: I'm sorry but I still don't get what is the issue,there are many sites that will teach you how to work with the framework,some even explain how to build a website from 0 using laravel.I personally recommend on [Laracasts - Laravel 5 Fundamentals](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals) it will teach you the basics for free.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll Try to answer my question.
I take it from [Facebook Group Laravel Indonesia](https://www.facebook.com/groups/laravel/permalink/584682361670124/)

- Create directory `app/libraries`
- Add `app/libraries` to `composer.json`

  `"classmap": ["database","app/libraries"],`
- Create `MD5Hasher.php` in `app/libraries`

  ```php
  <?php    
  namespace App\Libraries;        
  use Illuminate\Contracts\Hashing\Hasher as HasherContract;

  class MD5Hasher implements HasherContract {

  public function make($value, array $options = array()) {
  $value = env('SALT', '').$value;
  return md5($value);
  }

  public function check($value, $hashedValue, array $options = array()) {
  return $this->make($value) === $hashedValue;
  }

  public function needsRehash($hashedValue, array $options = array()) {
  return false;
  }

  }
  ```
- Create `MD5HashServiceProvider.php` in `app/libraries`

  ```php
  <?php

  namespace App\Libraries;

  use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

  class MD5HashServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

  /**
  * Register the service provider.
  *
  * @return void
  */
  public function register() {
  $this->app['hash'] = $this->app->share(function () {
  return new MD5Hasher();
  });

  }

  /**
  * Get the services provided by the provider.
  *
  * @return array
  */
  public function provides() {
  return array('hash');
  }

  }
  ```
- in `config/app.php`

  Find `Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider::class,`

  Change to `App\Libraries\MD5HashServiceProvider::class,`
- in `AuthController.php`

  Add `protected $username = 'username';`

  ```php
  return Validator::make($data, [
              //'name' => 'required|max:255',
              'username' => 'required',
              'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:5',
          ]);
  ```

  ```php
  return User::create([
              //'name' => $data['name'],
              'username' => $data['username'],
              'password' => md5($data['password']),
          ]);
  ```
- in `App\Users.php`

  Change `protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password'];`

  To `protected $fillable = ['username', 'password'];`
- Don't forget to run `composer dumpautoload`

I don't know what I am doing is right or not.

Regard

Comment: "classmap": ["database","app/libraries"], where in composer.json ?  @Anggagewor "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    }, here ?