# Laravel 5.1 Multiple Auth With two database

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5.1

Continue from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32667257/custom-auth-and-hashing-laravel-5-1)

Lets say I have :

```
Database_one:
users[
username,
password
]
```

And

```
Database_two:
employee[
username,
password
]
```

I was done make custom auth with `database_one` and work perfectly.
in the same application, I want to create same auth but with `database_two`

I was found default auth laravel is

```
App\User
App\Http\Controllers\Auth
Config\Auth
```

What I must do now ?
copy-paste default laravel auth file and change/modif value ?
Or how ?

I am new to laravel,

Thanks for Adv.

Angga.

Comment: This is not the right way to do this. Have one single table for handling users. Store all of the information, then have a separate table for employees. Remember the rules in inheritance: `A [USER] CAN BE [employee]` no need to store information twice.