# Laravel - change password hashing of laravel from BCRYPT to MD5

Tags: laravel

I am working on a small project that requires the registration of the password of my user is in MD5.

I know that for more security it's better to use BCRYPT,
but I'm trying to find out if there is a way to implement something more simple

Comment: It's *harder* to do it the bad way in Laravel. It's built around strong password hashing, and you should use that strong hashing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32686882/916000

Comment: Why does it require MD5?  Is it because you already have passwords stored that way and you don't know how to change them over?  Because you could pretty easily edit your login controller to check the existing MD5 hash on first login, then rehash the password using Laravel's hash facade for future use.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected function create(Request $request)
{
    $user= User::create([
        'username' => $request->user_name,
        'email' => $request->email,
        'password' => md5($request->password),

    ]);
}
```

Comment: This is only one of the steps necessary.