# Laravel 5.2 - How to authenticate users with a MD5 password database column

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I'm building an application with `Laravel 5.2` and I'd like to login users with usernames and passwords that are stored in a different database with password in `md5($salt.$password)` style. I **CANNOT** move to a different cypher like `bcrypt` currently due to access limitations. I only need to handle the login of the users. How can I do this?

I've already tried with a class that extends EloquentUserProvider and overrides validateCredentials method but with no luck.

I'm searching for a solution on laravel 5. i think the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33562285/how-can-i-use-md5-hashing-for-passwords-in-laravel) is about laravel 4 and some things maybe changed?

Comment: Why don't you want to use something more secure?

Comment: Unfortunately I have only read access to this table (the user data are managed by another applications i can't touch at this moment)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use MD5 hashing for passwords in Laravel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33562285/how-can-i-use-md5-hashing-for-passwords-in-laravel)

Comment: That solution which you think isn't for laravel 4.

Comment: sorry guys, you were right. [The solution linked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33562285/how-can-i-use-md5-hashing-for-passwords-in-laravel) was right. now it works! thank you!