# Custom fields and custom hash in laravel 5 authentication

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-authorization

I have been looking all over the Internet and many articles, but things I've tried just are not working.  What I want to do is very simple.  I have an existing database with columns email, securepass and secureid.  When a user logs in I want to check that the email, securepass and secureid they have supplied matches with the database.

The additional complication is that the securepass and secureid have to use sha256 for the authentication as that's what they are stored as in the database.  I can't use Laravel's bcrypt default.

What is the best way to do this?  Should I use the Eloquent ORM?  Should I create my own user provider or my own user driver?  I just don't know and a lot of the articles I've read don't always distinguish between Laravel 4 and 5.  The database is standard MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Can you go through the following links. It may helpful for you

https://github.com/expstudio/Laravel-4-Builerplate-Startup/blob/master/vendor/passwordlib/passwordlib/lib/PasswordLib/Password/Implementation/SHA256.php

[How to use SHA1 encryption instead of BCrypt in Laravel 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17710897/how-to-use-sha1-encryption-instead-of-bcrypt-in-laravel-4)

http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php

Comment: Thanks that gives me the answer for the sha256 part of my question.  But what about the custom fields?  Can I still use Eloquent?  Do I need to create my own driver?