# How to use MD5 instead BCrypt for password in Laravel 5.3?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

How to use `MD5` instead `BCrypt` for password in Laravel 5.3?

Comment: perhaps adapting [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17710897/how-to-use-sha1-encryption-instead-of-bcrypt-in-laravel-4) to the new laravel..

Comment: Hi @BagusTesa, your solution is Laravel 4, I need for Laravel 5.3

Comment: i know, but it never hurt to try. cause even in L5.3, IOC is still available, not to mention the providers and contracts workflow is still the same. sorry, but i can't fiddle on php..

Comment: @BagusTesa Thank you for help me :-)

Comment: Please don't do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Laravel 5.3 you can change `bcrypt()` to MD5 related logic in the `RegisterController.php` and override [`login()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php#L29) method in `LoginController.php` to [manually authenticate users](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication#authenticating-users) using MD5 related logic.

Comment: @mySun copy it to the `LoginController.php` and edit it there.

Comment: @mySun While this may allow you to do what you're trying to do, you should not be doing what you're trying to do. `MD5` is not a suitable hashing algorithm for password storage. The industry standard is `bcrypt`. Why do extra work in your application to intentionally make it less secure?

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure why no one has mentioned this yet but, You should not be using MD5 to protect passwords at this point. If that is what you are doing, you may as well just leave them plain text.

Answer (score 0):

Using md5 instead bcrypt is not legit, though you can achieve this quite easily.I did it in my lumen project which is miniframe of laravel

go to folder like `vendor`-->`illuminate`--> `auth`--> `EloquentUserProvider`

in `EloquentUserProvider` rewrite this like below codes

```
 public function validateCredentials(UserContract $user, array $credentials)
{
    $plain = $credentials['password'];


    if(md5($plain)==$user->getAuthPassword())
    {
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }


}
```

and when you are creating user take password input as `password'=>md5($request->input('password'))`

if youre using JWT you can generate token also `$token=app('auth')->attempt($request->only('email','password'));`