# Changing Default Bcrypt to sha1 in Laravel 8 jetstream while logging in a user

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-jetstream

I have an old project using sha1 encryption. Now I want to upgrade it with laravel jetstream, how can I override the default laravel authentication system which is Auth::attempt() in order to match the user when logging in with sha1 on the database/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to rewrite the Hash module, to do this you can see this answer :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17719586/4909223